# Not able to iterate properly over hash in my continuous input program (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration

I am trying to see if I can create a list of user input requests with a hash in this program I am trying to create. Whats the best way to go about this?

```
print "would you like to begin a changeover? (y/n) "
input = gets.chomp

tracking = {
  "start time" => input.Time.now,
  "Type?" => input,
  "shift?" => input,
  "standard hrs?" => input,
  "actual hrs?" => input,
  "end time" => input = gets.chomp.Time.now
}

tracking.each do |key, value|
  puts "great please answer the following: #{tracking}"
end
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do. Can you describe in more detail? Do you want to ask a user for six different things then put answers into a hash?

Comment: Hi Amadan, 

thanks for replying I am relatively new to Ruby, and would like to try to get input from the user to answer the questions with in the hash. I would like the beginning and end of the "Questionnaire" to mark the start and end time/date of a process. Is this possible? or should I try a different approach? I felt this way I would save a lot of time and code. any tips would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that the evaluation is sequential, going from top to bottom (unless you are defining functions/methods). In your code:

- You ask the user about a changeover
- You get user input (say, `y`) into the variable `input`
- You make a hash, with six values; four of them will contain `y`, two of them will contain current time
- You iterate over the hash, printing its values (and asking the user nothing).

Or at least it would if `gets.chomp.Time.now` was not an error.

So, taking care about the timing:

```
print "would you like to begin a changeover? (y/n) "
unless gets.chomp.tolower == 'n'
  puts "great please answer the following:"

  tracking = {
    "start time" => Time.now
  }

  [
    "Type?",
    "shift?",
    "standard hrs?",
    "actual hrs?"
  ].each do |question|
    print question
    tracking[question] = gets.chomp
  }

  tracking["end_time"] = Time.now
end
```

Comment: Thanks Alot! This set me on the right track, however it was not time stamping the beginning and end of the process the way I hoped, but after playing with it a bit I was able to get the results i wanted. The code ended up looking like this:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alot! This set me on the right track. However, was not time stamping the beginning and end of the questionnaire the way I wanted. After playing with the code a bit on my own however, I was able to make it work.

```
print "would you like to begin a changeover? (y/n) "
unless gets.chomp. == "n"
    puts Time.now
```

puts "great please answer the following: "

end

```
    questionnaire = ["Type", "Shift?", "Standard hrs?", "Actual hrs?"]
    .each do |question|
        puts question
        questionnaire = gets.chomp

end
```

puts "Please type 'done' when change over complete"
            input = gets.chomp
            puts Time.now